Fetch specific JSON object from a JSON file and make it to write at another JSON file
In postman project,I am maintaining multiple variables in a single enviornment JSON file.
To maintain code,I want to fetch specific which means required objects from the JSON file and do write in new JSON file.(For Example From Attached Pic),Want to fetch object which is having key name as "UTCDateTime" and write it into a separate JSON file.
Is it possible in JS?
Thanks in advance
{
"id": "6****8-1b78-48af-aff2-28******4565",
"name": "Dev_C@of@g_@ile",
"values": [
    {
        "key": "JobName",
        "value": "QATest123",
        "type": "any",
        "enabled": true
    },
    {
        "key": "JobIdentity",
        "value": "12356",
        "type": "any",
        "enabled": true
    },
    {
        "key": "JobData",
        "value": "[\"Asia/Almaty\",\"Asia/Amman\",\"Asia/Anadyr\",\"Asia/Aqtau\",\"Asia/Aqtobe\",\"Asia/Ashgabat\",\"Asia/Atyrau\",\"Asia/Baghdad\",\"Asia/Baku\",\"Asia/Bangkok\",\"Asia/Barnaul\",\"Asia/Beirut\",\"Asia/Bishkek\",\"Asia/Chita\",\"Asia/Choibalsan\",\"Asia/Colombo\",\"Asia/Damascus\",\"Asia/Dhaka\",\"Asia/Dili\",\"Asia/Dubai\",\"Asia/Dushanbe\",\"Asia/Famagusta\",\"Asia/Gaza\",\"Asia/Hebron\",\"Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh\",\"Asia/Hong_Kong\",\"Asia/Hovd\",\"Asia/Irkutsk\",\"Asia/Jakarta\",\"Asia/Jayapura\",\"Asia/Jerusalem\",\"Asia/Kabul\",\"Asia/Kamchatka\",\"Asia/Karachi\",\"Asia/Kathmandu\",\"Asia/Khandyga\",\"Asia/Kolkata\",\"Asia/Krasnoyarsk\",\"Asia/Kuching\",\"Asia/Macau\",\"Asia/Magadan\",\"Asia/Makassar\",\"Asia/Manila\",\"Asia/Nicosia\",\"Asia/Novokuznetsk\",\"Asia/Novosibirsk\",\"Asia/Omsk\",\"Asia/Oral\",\"Asia/Pontianak\",\"Asia/Pyongyang\",\"Asia/Qatar\",\"Asia/Qostanay\",\"Asia/Qyzylorda\",\"Asia/Riyadh\",\"Asia/Sakhalin\",\"Asia/Samarkand\",\"Asia/Seoul\",\"Asia/Shanghai\",\"Asia/Singapore\",\"Asia/Srednekolymsk\",\"Asia/Taipei\",\"Asia/Tashkent\",\"Asia/Tbilisi\",\"Asia/Tehran\",\"Asia/Thimphu\",\"Asia/Tokyo\",\"Asia/Tomsk\",\"Asia/Ulaanbaatar\",\"Asia/Urumqi\",\"Asia/Ust-Nera\",\"Asia/Vladivostok\",\"Asia/Yakutsk\",\"Asia/Yangon\",\"Asia/Yekaterinburg\",\"Asia/Yerevan\"]",
        "type": "any",
        "enabled": true
    }
],
"_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
"_postman_exported_at": "2024-05-06T12:22:19.783Z",
"_postman_exported_using": "Postman/11.0.6"

}

Two questions, #1 The "UTCDateTime" key have no value, why you want to save a separate JSON file? #2  Separate JSON need to save own environment JSON file or not?

@BenchVue Above pic is posted just for sample.In Actual,JSON contains value.I have edited the picture in my question

@BenchVue Yes....For saving own environment file in specific key-value wise,need to separate JSON.....

I see it is possible, your new image JSON clipped, I can see only partial. Can you update with JSON source text instead of image? , you can put the code block in here.

@BenchVue HI...I have attached the sample format code

I answered can you try it?

@BenchVue Hi..Thanks a lot..But i want to separare json array using particular key.For example,I want to split only one json array key value as "JobName" ...I having more than 300 json object value....I am getting 300 json file when using the below script...I want to get some specfic json array...Is it possible

shows your real JSON and explain more detail. I will try it.

I update my answer for filtering only specific key file. Is it work for you?

OK, You can modify and understand my code. Happy coding!

This code can generate environment JSON files.
The script reads a JSON file containing environment data.
It iterates through each key-value pair, creating a new JSON object for each key.
It writes each JSON object to a separate file, using the key as the prefix in the file name.
Demo
Save as demo.js
const fs = require('fs');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const inputFileName = 'data.postman_environment.json'; // Read the input JSON file
const inputFileContent = fs.readFileSync(inputFileName, 'utf8');

const data = JSON.parse(inputFileContent); // Parse the JSON content

// Iterate over each key in the JSON object
data.values.forEach((item, index) => {
    const id = uuidv4(); // Generate a random UUID for each key

    // Create a new JSON object
    const outputData = {
        id,
        name: `${item.key}`,
        values: [item],
        _postman_variable_scope: data._postman_variable_scope,
        _postman_exported_at: data._postman_exported_at,
        _postman_exported_using: data._postman_exported_using
    };

    // Write each JSON object to a separate file
    const outputFileName = `${item.key}.postman_environment.json`;
    fs.writeFileSync(outputFileName, JSON.stringify(outputData, null, 4));

    console.log(`File '${outputFileName}' created.`);
});

Input environment JSON
Save as data.postman_environment.json
{
    "id": "6****8-1b78-48af-aff2-28******4565",
    "name": "Dev_C@of@g_@ile",
    "values": [
        {
            "key": "JobName",
            "value": "QATest123",
            "type": "any",
            "enabled": true
        },
        {
            "key": "JobIdentity",
            "value": "12356",
            "type": "any",
            "enabled": true
        },
        {
            "key": "JobData",
            "value": "[\"Asia/Almaty\",\"Asia/Amman\",\"Asia/Anadyr\",\"Asia/Aqtau\",\"Asia/Aqtobe\",\"Asia/Ashgabat\",\"Asia/Atyrau\",\"Asia/Baghdad\",\"Asia/Baku\",\"Asia/Bangkok\",\"Asia/Barnaul\",\"Asia/Beirut\",\"Asia/Bishkek\",\"Asia/Chita\",\"Asia/Choibalsan\",\"Asia/Colombo\",\"Asia/Damascus\",\"Asia/Dhaka\",\"Asia/Dili\",\"Asia/Dubai\",\"Asia/Dushanbe\",\"Asia/Famagusta\",\"Asia/Gaza\",\"Asia/Hebron\",\"Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh\",\"Asia/Hong_Kong\",\"Asia/Hovd\",\"Asia/Irkutsk\",\"Asia/Jakarta\",\"Asia/Jayapura\",\"Asia/Jerusalem\",\"Asia/Kabul\",\"Asia/Kamchatka\",\"Asia/Karachi\",\"Asia/Kathmandu\",\"Asia/Khandyga\",\"Asia/Kolkata\",\"Asia/Krasnoyarsk\",\"Asia/Kuching\",\"Asia/Macau\",\"Asia/Magadan\",\"Asia/Makassar\",\"Asia/Manila\",\"Asia/Nicosia\",\"Asia/Novokuznetsk\",\"Asia/Novosibirsk\",\"Asia/Omsk\",\"Asia/Oral\",\"Asia/Pontianak\",\"Asia/Pyongyang\",\"Asia/Qatar\",\"Asia/Qostanay\",\"Asia/Qyzylorda\",\"Asia/Riyadh\",\"Asia/Sakhalin\",\"Asia/Samarkand\",\"Asia/Seoul\",\"Asia/Shanghai\",\"Asia/Singapore\",\"Asia/Srednekolymsk\",\"Asia/Taipei\",\"Asia/Tashkent\",\"Asia/Tbilisi\",\"Asia/Tehran\",\"Asia/Thimphu\",\"Asia/Tokyo\",\"Asia/Tomsk\",\"Asia/Ulaanbaatar\",\"Asia/Urumqi\",\"Asia/Ust-Nera\",\"Asia/Vladivostok\",\"Asia/Yakutsk\",\"Asia/Yangon\",\"Asia/Yekaterinburg\",\"Asia/Yerevan\"]",
            "type": "any",
            "enabled": true
        }
    ],
    "_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
    "_postman_exported_at": "2024-05-06T12:22:19.783Z",
    "_postman_exported_using": "Postman/11.0.6"
}

Install dependency
npm install uuid

Run it
node demo.js

Result

JobData.postman_environment.json
{
    "id": "0c51c1f6-25c8-4c52-b46c-bb2bf7761be0",
    "name": "JobData",
    "values": [
        {
            "key": "JobData",
            "value": "[\"Asia/Almaty\",\"Asia/Amman\",\"Asia/Anadyr\",\"Asia/Aqtau\",\"Asia/Aqtobe\",\"Asia/Ashgabat\",\"Asia/Atyrau\",\"Asia/Baghdad\",\"Asia/Baku\",\"Asia/Bangkok\",\"Asia/Barnaul\",\"Asia/Beirut\",\"Asia/Bishkek\",\"Asia/Chita\",\"Asia/Choibalsan\",\"Asia/Colombo\",\"Asia/Damascus\",\"Asia/Dhaka\",\"Asia/Dili\",\"Asia/Dubai\",\"Asia/Dushanbe\",\"Asia/Famagusta\",\"Asia/Gaza\",\"Asia/Hebron\",\"Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh\",\"Asia/Hong_Kong\",\"Asia/Hovd\",\"Asia/Irkutsk\",\"Asia/Jakarta\",\"Asia/Jayapura\",\"Asia/Jerusalem\",\"Asia/Kabul\",\"Asia/Kamchatka\",\"Asia/Karachi\",\"Asia/Kathmandu\",\"Asia/Khandyga\",\"Asia/Kolkata\",\"Asia/Krasnoyarsk\",\"Asia/Kuching\",\"Asia/Macau\",\"Asia/Magadan\",\"Asia/Makassar\",\"Asia/Manila\",\"Asia/Nicosia\",\"Asia/Novokuznetsk\",\"Asia/Novosibirsk\",\"Asia/Omsk\",\"Asia/Oral\",\"Asia/Pontianak\",\"Asia/Pyongyang\",\"Asia/Qatar\",\"Asia/Qostanay\",\"Asia/Qyzylorda\",\"Asia/Riyadh\",\"Asia/Sakhalin\",\"Asia/Samarkand\",\"Asia/Seoul\",\"Asia/Shanghai\",\"Asia/Singapore\",\"Asia/Srednekolymsk\",\"Asia/Taipei\",\"Asia/Tashkent\",\"Asia/Tbilisi\",\"Asia/Tehran\",\"Asia/Thimphu\",\"Asia/Tokyo\",\"Asia/Tomsk\",\"Asia/Ulaanbaatar\",\"Asia/Urumqi\",\"Asia/Ust-Nera\",\"Asia/Vladivostok\",\"Asia/Yakutsk\",\"Asia/Yangon\",\"Asia/Yekaterinburg\",\"Asia/Yerevan\"]",
            "type": "any",
            "enabled": true
        }
    ],
    "_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
    "_postman_exported_at": "2024-05-06T12:22:19.783Z",
    "_postman_exported_using": "Postman/11.0.6"
}

JobIdentity.postman_environment.json
{
    "id": "279b06d1-1655-469f-8aef-c72681ac881f",
    "name": "JobIdentity",
    "values": [
        {
            "key": "JobIdentity",
            "value": "12356",
            "type": "any",
            "enabled": true
        }
    ],
    "_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
    "_postman_exported_at": "2024-05-06T12:22:19.783Z",
    "_postman_exported_using": "Postman/11.0.6"
}

JobName.postman_environment.json
{
    "id": "9dcbc812-5e75-4c34-a033-28f8c638352a",
    "name": "JobName",
    "values": [
        {
            "key": "JobName",
            "value": "QATest123",
            "type": "any",
            "enabled": true
        }
    ],
    "_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
    "_postman_exported_at": "2024-05-06T12:22:19.783Z",
    "_postman_exported_using": "Postman/11.0.6"
}


Edit
If you want to save specific key only, add an if statement.
data.values.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item.key == 'JobData') {
        const id = uuidv4(); // Generate a random UUID for each key

        // Create a new JSON object
        const outputData = {
            id,
            name: `${item.key}`,
            values: [item],
            _postman_variable_scope: data._postman_variable_scope,
            _postman_exported_at: data._postman_exported_at,
            _postman_exported_using: data._postman_exported_using
        };
    
        // Write each JSON object to a separate file
        const outputFileName = `${item.key}.postman_environment.json`;
        fs.writeFileSync(outputFileName, JSON.stringify(outputData, null, 4));
    
        console.log(`File '${outputFileName}' created.`);
    }
});

It will save only JobData.postman_environment.json.

This code is in python 3:

with open('[The file name you are reading]', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    
    with open('[The file name you are writing to]', 'w') as r:
        loaded = json.dumps(f, r, indent=2)```


Hi...Thansk for your reply....I need to do in Javascript....
